# Beginner (classic) Fizzbuzz while loop not working

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I wrote the required while loop for my assignment but I am getting an error.

```
var x = 1 ;

while (x <= 20) {

    if( x % 3 === 0 ) {
        console.log( "Julia" );

    }

    else if( x % 5 === 0 ) {
        console.log( "James" );

    }

    else if( x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 0 ) {

        console.log( "JuliaJames" );

    }

    else{
        console.log(x);

    }
    x++;

}
```

........

and here are the directions

Directions:
Write a while loop that:

Loops through the numbers 1 to 20
If the number is divisible by 3, print "Julia"
If the number is divisible by 5, print "James"
If the number is divisible by 3 and 5, print "JuliaJames"
If the number is not divisible by 3 or 5, print the number

When i run the code, each number within the range is either kept as a number or replaced by the word "James", "Julia", or "JuliaJames".

I am submitting my code as written above but am told "Verify that your while loop is producing the correct output"

Comment: Think about how the number 15 is related to the numbers 3 and 5, and what happens as your code moves through the `if` tests.

Comment: Change `while loop` to `for loop` statement, remove all `else` and use `continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to check for x%5 && x%3 first, and then x%5 before x%3 in your conditionals. Otherwise an x%3 that is also a x%5 (such as 15), will hit the x%3 but never go into the x%5 && x%3 or x%5 conditional.

```
var x = 1;

while (x <= 20) {
  if (x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("JuliaJames");
  } else if (x % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("James");
  } else if (x % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Julia");
  } else {
    console.log(x);
  }
  x++;
}
```

Comment: It can check for both 3 and 5 by checking `x % 15` first.

Answer (score 0):

That last else if statement will never be true because the two conditions required for it (mod 3 and mod 5) trigger the above if statements, so any value meeting those requirements will never get that far.  Try moving that last if statement (JuliaJames) so it's the first if statement, that should fix the problem.